# Mongoose: Running a second query on the returned documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

**Problem:**

I have a 'Group' collection. Each group has an embedded document of 'Members'. I need to pull out a specific Member by their 'MemberID' and fetch all their details from the 'Users' collection. I would like to do this using the '.populate()' method but only need to populate that single member's record not all the members records.

So my query looks like this:

```
DB.model('groups')
.findById(groupID)
.populate('members._user')
.run(function(err, group){

    // then loop over every member and return the one that matches 
    // the member id we require

});
```

This seems like a very inefficient way of doing things considering I only need the user details for one member in the group! I only have the memberID not the userID so this is the reason I am going to the members collection.

**How can I extract a single member from the embedded 'members' document and populate it?**

Comment: Is `members` field in your `group` a document or an array of documents?

Comment: An array of embedded documents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `populate` function takes 3 parameters: `path`, `fields` and `conditions`. `fields` and `conditions` are applied when the referred document(s) is(are) populated via a separate call to `model.find(...)`. Try passing to `populate` a valid mongodb condition that will only return members that you are interested in.

Comment: Ah interesting! How do you state the conditions? Where can I find documentation on this?

Comment: I looked through the sources of mongoose to find the parameters of `populate` and see find out how they are used internally.